# BST pre-order deletion

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, preorder

I would like to know if it is possible to free an entire binary search tree in preorder mode. I've got this function:

```
void preorder_del(struct s_nodo ** tree)
{
     if (*tree != NULL)
        {
          free(*tree);
          preorder_del(&(*tree)->left);
          preorder_del(&(*tree)->right);
        }
}
```

I don't think this works, freeing the first leaf of the tree wont let me recall preorder, right?

Comment: If you free the node, how do you expect to `tree->left` and `tree->right` be anything sensible?

Answer (score 2):

You should record `left` and `right` locally to avoid accessing freed pointer after `free(*tree)`.

```
 if (*tree != NULL)
 {
      struct s_nodo *l = (*tree)->left;
      struct s_nodo *r = (*tree)->right;
      free(*tree);
      preorder_del(&l);
      preorder_del(&r);
 }
```

Comment: It doesnt work in my mac. "malloc: *** error for object 0x9000000000000000: pointer being freed was not allocated"

Comment: @SebastianC Edited. We should not record `&(*tree)->left` since it's also freed by `free(*tree)`.

Comment: free(*tree) what exactly does? delete all the leafs, or just the one pointed?

Comment: I dont understand then why we should record &(*tree)->left, if free just free the leaf pointed

Comment: `(*tree)->left` is a part of `*tree`, thus the memory space storing it was freed up at the time of `free(*tree)`. After that, accessing `(*tree)->left` leads to undefined behavior.